# Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAsync'

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing a javascript plugin for outlook.

I did the testing on outlook web because it has a better debugger and it works fine on outlook web, now the plugin is in the final stage.
Now I ran the plugin on outlook desktop and got this error.

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAsync'

```
function getItemBody(){
    console.log("Inside getItemBody().");
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
        "text",
        { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
        function callback(result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.asyncContext);
            console.log(result.value);
            var s = "Document_ID";
            if (result.value.indexOf(s) !== -1){
                console.log("Document id found.");
                var substring = result.value.split(':').pop().split('.')[0];
                document_uuid = substring;
                localStorage.setItem("document_uuid", document_uuid);

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=office-js#methods) says that you need at least set : Mailbox 1.3. Can you check if this is the case? You can provide the requirement like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

Comment: In Outlook desktop, you can use Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#use-runtime-checks-in-your-javascript-code) to determine if the client implements the requirement set you need to call the API.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes, my mailbox version is 1.1, can you tell me how should I update my mailbox to 1.3 in order to use .getAsync() ? or can I use this method without updating my mailbox version?

Comment: @Ahsaan-566 I'd say start with [adding the version requirement to the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets). This way the addin can't be used if the version doesn't match. Then concerning the actual client version, supported versions for each client are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#clients). The note below shows in which update the support for certain versions was added.